# unable to install s3cmd on centos

Tags: centos, s3cmd

I tried the following commands to install s3cmd on centos on centos-release-6-8

```
cd etc/yum.repos.d
wget http://s3tools.org/repo/RHEL_6/s3tools.repo
yum install s3cmd
```

last command output "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"

i tried sudo yum install s3cmd. it was also not working

any help?

Answer (score 0):

My yum command was not working.

```
root@server [/etc/yum.repos.d]# export NSS_DISABLE_HW_AES=1
```

and it fixed the problem and s3cmd was installed